# How to filter DateTime by year with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

When i have to filter by date (only year), i use the prperty on the DateTime object like this:

```
var myQuery = from p in logEntryList
             where p.Logdate.Year > 2013
            select p.Title;
```

to get all entries after 2013-12-31.. 
My colleague reviewed my code, and corrected my linq-statement to this:

```
var myQuery = from p in logEntryList
             where p.Logdate > Convert.ToDateTime("2013-12-31")
            select p.Title;
```

He's comment: "it would be better..."

We only have to filter by year not by date or time.. The results are the same.. but which one is 'better'? Is my solution really wrong or bad practice?

Datatype `Title = String & Logdate = DateTime`

Comment: If your LogDate is not date but also time, then the queries would give different results. Second query would include the logs on 2013-12-13

Comment: IMO, they're both just as good.  Not sure what his point is.

Comment: Doing a comparison on each execution time. The initial code written by you would be 7x faster than the second one (given by your friend). I considered a list containing 1000 samples.

Comment: @JustinRusso Not so, as the original query will have results starting at midnight on January 1 2014, while the "corrected" version will have results starting just after midnight on December 31, 2013. Depending on the data contained, the results could be different (incorrect). And as pointed out in the answers, there are much faster ways of doing this.

Comment: @mason, yes, I was inaccurate.  The 'Corrected' version is absolutely wrong!!!  It will include results from '12/31/2013'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, if his goal was optimization (my best guess) he's sort of on the right track but is also wrong.

Internally, `DateTime` doesn't store the date as separate parts of year, month, day, etc. Instead, when you use the `Year` property it invokes an algorithm to calculate the `DateTime`'s year.

He likely wanted to optimize out this calculation. However, in his case, the `Convert.ToDateTime` call will also be called for every entry, which defeats the purpose. To optimize it, you'd want to do something like this:

```
DateTime fromDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2014-01-01");

var myQuery = from p in logEntryList
              where p.Logdate >= fromDate
              select p.Title;
```

A simple ordering compare like this, rather than a more complex operation like using `Year`, also maps best to a database where an eligible index might be present. So in the right cicumstances, it will not only be more efficient CPU-wise, but also I/O-wise if you're using a database.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use 2014-01-01 for the `fromDate`, and then use `>=`? Otherwise results from the last day of 2013 will be in, which doesn't appear intended based on the original query.

Comment: @mason You're correct. I was optimizing his code but didn't think to correct it! I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Small changes can make big difference. Convert IN the linq state is definitely wrong.. :)

Answer (score 3):

Your code will not yield any dates on the last day of the year, 12/31.  The second snippet will yield all dates on 12/31 that are after midnight.

Your code is correct (assuming you don't *want* to include 12/31, which I assume you do not), and his is not.  Everything else is of lower priority.

Comment: +1, that is definitely right. The second comparison would include records for last day of December as well

Comment: Jap that is true.. luckily we have only records with a time 00:00:00.